# How can I display a list of three different Models sortable by the same :attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, models

I have a Campaign model which has_many Calls, Emails, and Letters.

For now, these are each a separate Model with different controllers and actions (although I would like to start to think of ways to collapse them once the models and actions stabilize).

They do share two attributes at least: :days and :title

I would like a way to represent all the Calls, Emails, and Letters that belong_to a specific Campaign as a sortable collection (sortable by :days), in a way that outputs the model name and the path_to() for each.

For example (I know the below is not correct, but it represents the kind of output/format I've been trying to do:

```
@campaign_events.each do |campaign_event|
  <%= campaign_event.model_name %>
  <%= link_to campaign_event.title, #{model_name}_path(campaign_event) %>
end
```

Thanks so much.  BTW, if this matters, I would then want to make the :days attribute editable_in_place.

**Here is what I've got working, but want some additional insights**

```
module CampaignsHelper
  def campaign_events
    return (@campaign.calls + @campaign.emails + @campaign.letters).sort{|a,b| a.days <=> b.days}
  end
end
```

In the VIEW:

```
<% @campaign_events = campaign_events %>
<% @campaign_events.each do |campaign_event| %>
    <% model_name = campaign_event.class.name.tableize.singularize %>
    <p>
        <%= link_to campaign_event.title,  send("#{model_name}_path", campaign_event) %> 
        <%= campaign_event.days %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
# controller
@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
@campaign_events = (@campaign.calls + @campaign.emails + @campaign.letters).sort{|a,b| a.days <=> b.days}

# view
@campaign_events.each do |campaign_event|
  <%= campaign_event.model_name %>
  <%= link_to campaign_event.title, #{model_name}_path(campaign_event) %>
end
```

In controller you find all campaign events and sort it by `days` field

Comment: I'd make campaign_events a model method instead of calculating it on a controller.

Comment: How do I extract the campaign_event.model_name?  campaign_event.class.name.tableize.singularize ?

Comment: ah, so in application_helper def campaign_events ?

Comment: I made some adjustments to get the link working properly, created a campaign_helper, and it works, but wanted another pair of eyes...